# Java memory usage - is this syntax correct or it will cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

```
HashMap obj = new HashMap();
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    obj = getObjects(i);
}
```

Will this code cause a memory leak at this line "obj = getObjects(i);"?

I'm not sure if the old values of obj are released or if they are still using the memory.

If this is a memory leak what is the correct syntax?

Comment: The HashMap that obj was pointing to before the assignment would get garbage collected as there won't be any references to it but there is no guarantee that it will happen as soon as the assignment is done. Garbage collection will happen eventually.

Comment: Please don't use raw-types like HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java there is a garbage collector, so using normal operations like this it is pretty hard to cause a memory leak. The garbage collector goes around freeing any memory that is no longer referenced.

More info on garbage collection: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

The short answer is that your code should not cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

A reference or object is not "released" when it is overwritten. There is no more work in assigning a reference as assigning one `int` to a variable.

Instead the the old reference simply no longer exists, and GC looks for references which still exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this code cause a memory leak at this line "obj = getObjects(i);"?

It is impossible to say for sure.  You haven't shown us the code for `getObjects`, and it is possible (though not likely, based on the method's name) that that method could have an internal memory leak.

However, repeatedly assigning references to a simple variable (e.g. `obj`) will not leak memory.

> I'm not sure if the old values of obj are released or if they are still using the memory.

It is not as simple at that:

- From a storage management perspective, the "old values of obj" are references ... not objects.
- The objects that those references refer to will not be released immediately when you assign a different reference to `obj`.
- They will eventually be released in the future by the GC, provided that:

  - there is sufficient memory pressure to cause the GC to run for the "space" where the objects have been allocated, and
  - nothing else references the objects.

> If this is a memory leak what is the correct syntax?

For the record, memory leaks are not a syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test and is fine, java is periodicaly releasing memory.
I still used HashMap to reproduce my application context.

```
package memtest;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MemTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        HashMap obj = new HashMap();
        int loop = 1;
        while(true) {
            HashMap newObj = new HashMap();
            newObj.put("1", "big string that is not pasted here");
            obj = newObj;
            System.err.println("At loop "+loop);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            loop++;
        }
    }    
}
```